# Why does PHP's preg_split split the hebrew letter “נ” in UTF-8 when splitting on “\s”?

Tags: php, utf-8, whitespace, pcre, hebrew

This doesn't work, it turns it to gibberish:

```
$foo = 'נ';
$bar = mb_convert_encoding($foo, 'UTF-8', mb_detect_encoding($foo));
print_r(preg_split('/\s/', $bar));
```

> Array ( [0] => � [1] => )

But this works:

```
$foo = 'נ';
$bar = mb_convert_encoding($foo, 'ISO-8859-8', mb_detect_encoding($foo));
$baz = preg_split('/\s/', $bar);
echo(mb_convert_encoding($baz[0], 'UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-8'));
```

> נ

The problem is only with the letter "`נ`". It works fine with all the other Hebrew letters. Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When working with UTF-8 data, always use the [*u* modifier](http://php.net/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers) in your patterns:

```
/\s/u
```

Because otherwise the pattern is not interpreted as UTF-8.

Like in this case the character `נ` (U+05E0) is encoded with 0xD7A0 in UTF-8. And `\s` represents any whitespace character (according to [PCRE](http://pcre.org/pcre.txt)):

> The `\s` characters  are  HT  (9), LF (10), FF (12), CR (13), and space (32).

When UTF-8 support was added, they have also added a special option called PCRE_UCP to have `\b`, `\d`, `\s`, and `\w` not just match US-ASCII characters but also other Unicode characters by their Unicode properties:

> By default, in UTF-8 mode, characters  with  values  greater  than  128 never  match  `\d`,  `\s`,  or  `\w`,  and always match `\D`, `\S`, and `\W`. […] However, if PCRE is compiled with Unicode property support, and the PCRE_UCP option is set, the  behaviour  is  changed  so  that Unicode properties are used to determine character types, as follows:
>
> - `\d`  any character that `\p{Nd}` matches (decimal digit)
> - `\s`  any character that `\p{Z}` matches, plus HT, LF, FF, CR
> - `\w`  any character that `\p{L}` or `\p{N}` matches, plus underscore

And that non-breaking space U+00A0 has the property of a separator (`\p{Z}`).

So although your pattern is not in UTF-8 mode, it seems that `\s` *does* match that 0xA0 in the UTF-8 code word 0xD7A0, splitting the string at that position and returning an array that is equivalent to `array("\xD7", "")`.

And that’s obviously a bug as the pattern is *not* in UTF-8 mode but 0xA0 *is* greater than 0x80 (additionally, 0xA0 would be encoded as 0xC2A0). The [bug #52971 *PCRE-Meta-Characters not working with utf-8*](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52971) could be related with this.

Comment: @happytoad: I’ve added some possible explanation for this specific behavior.

Comment: People who are interested in the relationship between Unicode characters and Unicode properties, including also things like `\s` and `\v` (vertical space) and `\h` (horizontal space) should grab my two basic utilities programs, [*unichars*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/unichars) and [*uniprops*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uniprops). Instructions and examples are included. There’s also a third related program, [*uninames*](http://training.perl.com/scripts/uninames), which you might also like.